# How to run Multiple exe with “RunProgram” from 7zip sfx with config.txt?

Tags: exe, 7zip, sfx

Ive Tried this it only ever runs which ever instance of run program is first.
ive also tried with ExecuteFile.

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
Title="Title"
RunProgram="one.exe"
RunProgram="two.exe"
;!@InstallEnd@!
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Ok So i Created a cmd file called Run.cmd

```
@echo off
start one.exe && start two.exe
exit
```

and a config file

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
Title="Title"
RunProgram="hidcon:Run.cmd"
;!@InstallEnd@!
```

but i get the error specified file not found.
Removing the hidecon: fixes this problem but now the console is visible but barely.
but im getting an .inf file sying it canot be found for one or the program.
***!!!
For some reason if i open say just RungProgram="one.exe" it works fine but if i use RunProgram="Run.cmd" not all the files are extracted is this because the cmd.exe exits before the extraction is complete?.

Answer (score 2):

Create a .cmd file that runs the other programmes in sequence and then RunProgram that.

Comment: But that will be visible and look awful the 7zip sfx says that function can be used multiple times through out the config, so there must be a way to make it work. i also tried runprogram="one.exe", "two.exe" which didn't work either. Thans though

Comment: ive found the command RunProgram="hidcon:cmd install.cmd or somthign like that ill give it a try

Comment: Well, multiple programme binaries are visible just as much, so I'm not sure there's much of a difference there...

Comment: I think it's `RunProgram="hidcon:cmd Run.cmd"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [original distribution](http://www.7-zip.org/7z.html) you can't run two exe sequentially.But if you are using the [modified version](http://7zsfx.solta.ru/en/) of it.It will work.I've downloaded [7z SFX Tools](http://7zsfx.info/files/7zsd_tools_150_2712.7z), extracted it and renamed 7zsd_All.sfx to 7zS.sfx and used this configuration to run to applications in sequence.

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
RunProgram="setup.exe"
RunProgram="launcher-Win32.exe"
;!@InstallEnd@!
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest 7-Zip SFX Maker v3.3 will run 2 files consecutively...JT